# How to not allow direct 'cat' but allow from the C program

Tags: c, linux

I am coding a small piece of C program. Basically, in the folder will have to file: **secret.txt** and **code.c**. I want my user cannot use any means to directly print out the **secret.txt** in terminal by 'cat', 'head', etc. but they can read it from a C program.

How they can read it (in my C code):

```
if (<some conditional>){
   system("\bin\cat secret.txt");
}
```

I have tried to set the permissions of **secret.txt** as 440, the executable **code** as 4711. The file **secret.txt** is owned by root:root. And normal user can execute the **code**. However, in the program, it keeps saying permission denied.

How can I do this?

Comment: The program simply use the user permission. Why not just encrypt the file and decrypt it from the program (though it doesn't stop attacker from decompiling your program)?

Comment: `char buf[1024]; while (fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin) { fputs (buf, stdout);` and then either open the file in your program and replace `stdin` with the file pointer, or just redirect `secret.txt` to your program and read from `stdin`, e.g. `./program < secret.txt`. To deny `cat`, `head`, etc.. you would need to write a small shell and simply not respond to those commands.

Comment: I gather this is just a fun puzzle rather than a security issue.  If that is the case, you could put VT100 escape sequences in the file to erase the screen or something like that.  If the user reads it with `cat` in a normal terminal, their screen would get erased, but they could still read it with `head -c=NUM` or with a C program that filters out the escape sequences.

Comment: It is not enough to set the setuid bit  on the executable. You need to call `seteuid(0)` before attempting to do a privileged operation. By the way, calling `system` from a setuid program is a [security risk](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html#NOTES).

Comment: For starters : `"\bin\cat secret.txt"` -> `"/bin/cat secret.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

It would be very difficult (and wouldn't make that much sense usually) to deny a specific program from reading a file.

In Linux, permissions work per user, so if the c program and cat run with the same (effective) user-id, they will have the same permissions (generally).

The best way to solve it, if I correctly understood your intentions, is to compile your program, `chown` it to root, and make it a setuid binary (meaning that it will run with the permissions of "root" and not "user"). This way, it will run as root and be able to access the file.